# How to call a function containing multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, debugging, math, matrix, computer-science

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;

void compute_minor_sums (int a[][MAX], int B[][MAX], int n1, int n2){
    int sum=0,row[n2],col[n1];
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
            cin>>a[i][j];
            sum+=a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
            row[i]+=a[i][j];
            col[j]=col[j]+a[i][j];
        }
    }
   for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
            B[i][j]=sum-row[i]-col[j]+a[i][j];
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n1,n2;cin>>n1>>n2;
    int a[n1][n2],B[n1][n2];
     compute_minor_sums ( a, B,n1,n2);
    }
```

Program is about computing minor of an `n1*n2`  matrix.
I tried calling a function which computes minor.But I don't know exactly why is this giving these kind of errors? The first errors is:

```
Cannot convert int (*)[n2] to int int (*)[100]
```

The second error is:

```
Initialising argument 1 of void compute_minor_sums (int a[][MAX], int B[][MAX], int n1, int n2)
```

I can't use gdb as these errors are syntax errors.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: (1). c++ doesn't support VLAs (variable length arrays)     (2). The size of the array in the function declaration (MAX) should match what is actually passed.

Comment: I tried doing  compute_minor_sums ( a, B,n1,MAX);

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: The **static/fixed** size of `a` and `b` must match, not the size parameters `n1`, `n2`. And it must be static/fixed because c++ does not support VLAs as I wrote above.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not get what you are saying. The sizes of a&B are same as  declared inside the main function

Comment: The sizes in `main` are dynamic and dependant on user input. This is not valid in c++. The sizes must be constant (and the same as declared in the compute function).

Comment: In C++ it's better to use `std::vector` (or `std::array` but it doesn't fit here) instead of C-style array.

Answer (score 0):

The code is rewritten with vector.

(I'm not sure about matrix calculation logic.)

There would be memory bound errors if matrices are not square.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;

void compute_minor_sums(vector<vector<int>>& a, vector<vector<int>>B, int n1, int n2) {
    int sum = 0;
    vector<int> row(n2);
    vector<int>col(n1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            row[i] += a[i][j];
            col[j] = col[j] + a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            B[i][j] = sum - row[i] - col[j] + a[i][j];
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    vector<vector<int>> a(n1, vector<int>(n2)); // n1 x n2 matrix
    vector<vector<int>> B(n1, vector<int>(n2)); // n1 x n2 matrix
    compute_minor_sums(a, B, n1, n2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But vectors are not taught to us.  And it was not told that n1*n2 is a square matrix

Comment: The number of row[n2] and column[n1] are suspicious. Do you mean row[n1] and column[n2]?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code, I'll start with the few that are visible. As other users have mentioned in the comments - VLA doesn't exist in C++. What is a VLA?

The size of VLA's is determined during **runtime** and not during **compilation**. So the following code won't compile because values `n1` and `n2` are determined during **runtime by the user**.

```
int main()
{
  int n1,n2;
  std::cin >> n1 >> n2; // <-- we get values n1 and n2 during runtime from user input
  int a[n1][n2],B[n1][n2];
  //...
}
```

The following code will compile:

```
int main()
{
  const int n1 = 1;
  const int n2 = 2; // known during compilation and guaranteed not to change
  int a[n1][n2],B[n1][n2];
  int c[1][2]; // the same as using const ints - 1 and 2 are known during compilation
  //...
}
```

So you might be asking:

**What can we do if we do not know the size of the C-style array during compilation?**

The answer is, you can allocate the array on the **heap**, however to have a 2D array is no longer simple, i.e.:

```
int main()
{
  int n1,n2;
  std::cin >> n1 >> n2; // <-- we get values n1 and n2 during runtime from user input
  int **a = new int*[n1];
  for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i) {
    a[i] = new int[n2];
  }
}
```

We are as you can see creating pointers to pointers to `int`. Because array is just that - a pointer to an `int` which is the beginning of the array of `int` and the rest of the values are just offsets of the previous element.

We can also simplify the above by doing the following:

```
int* a = new int[n1 * n2];

// a[i][j] is then
a[i * n1 + j]
```

There are other issues with your code, but one thing at a time.

If you wish to pass it to the function, well you have more options now, but simply passing the **pointer to the beginning of the array** (i.e. `a`) is sufficient, however then you have to add some additional bound-checking logic. Hence why one of the answers suggested an `std` container called `std::vector` because these containers do all of this for you, with minimal overhead.

EDIT: The other issues with your code are for example here:

```
row[i]+=a[i][j];
col[j]=col[j]+a[i][j];
```

You do not initialize these arrays in your code, I'll be honest I'm not sure what is the default defined behavior for non-VLAs but when you allocate something on the *heap* as mentioned in my answer. You will get (most-likely) into undefined-behavior land with random values. So be sure to initialize row/col with default values (since you are doing mostly additions, you want to initialize with `0s`)

Comment: Oh!! Thank you!! I was getting this error with rows and columns. So,Do I need to initialize any array before doing any operation every time?

Comment: Depends on what `operation` (or what `operator`) are you doing (using). By initialization i mean the first assignment of a value to the given variable. The `+=` operator does (if you have `a += b`) this: `a = a+b` but if `a` is some random value, it will lead to unexpected behavior. So `a = 0; a += b` makes more sense here, because you prevent `a` from having a random value. Also be sure to read on stackoverflow community guidelines, i.e. if you've found this answer helpful, you should up-vote it. If you think it answers your question, you should mark it as the correct answer, good luck.